# ASA failover and L3 behind

Tags: cisco, asa

Here is my setup
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16923193/asa%20failover.JPG
As you can see, we have dual ASA 5512-X used for Internet access, VPN and so on, and L3 3560-X behind them, that’s connected to L2 access switches.

ASA config is ok so far. Failover is working between ASAs  (when primary fails, the secondary takes the config of the primary, and also the IPs of inside/outside addresses), but I don’t know how to configure GE 0/2 on 3560-X that’s behind the ASA?

I wanted to put it also with no switchport command, and ip address 10.101.0.4 255.255.255.0 but that overlaps GE 0/1 and L3 won’t let me do what. Is there a workaround with this one, so I can the L3 automatically switches over to GE 0/2 if primary ASA fails (in other words, if the connection with P-ASA to GE 0/1 L3 fails)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should brind up Ge0/1 and Ge0/2 on switch in switchport access mode and just configure a Vlan interface with L3 address 10.101.0.2/24.